# How to search inside of a search container in liferay

Tags: search, liferay

I have a search container that shows data from database. I want to put some input at top of it and search inside search container by this words.
Please give me some example to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

search container is a taglib that generates a certain HTML output and helps you to organize data in a way that results in a UI similar to that of Liferay itself.

There's no inherent "searchability", just because of the name. Further, it depends on what exactly you intend to do when you "search in search container": Do you need Ajax or do you just want to search in the currently displayed page?

Based on the underlying amount of data and the nature of it, my recommendation what to do would change. But "search container" is the wrong point to start looking for the solution IMHO